# Mocking a function with namespace confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-mock

I am trying to mock a function that should get called when calling a class method:

```
# SomeClass.py

from some_module import some_function


class SomeClass:
    
    def some_method(self, *a, **kw):
        ...
        some_function()
        ...
```

```
# tests.py

from mock import patch

from some_package.SomeClass import SomeClass


class TestSomeClass:
    
    @patch('SomeClass.some_function')  # <- error
    def test__some_function__called(self, mocked_function):
        ...
        SomeClass().some_method()
        mocked_function.assert_called()
```

However, I keep getting an error saying that `SomeClass` does not have a method called `some_function`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the fact that the module name and the class name are the same, i.e. `SomeClass`. This is causing `patch` some confusion.

The solution: a combination of `importlib` and overriding the imported modules function with `Mock()`:

```
# tests.py

import importlib
from mock import Mock

from some_package.SomeClass import SomeClass


class TestSomeClass:
    
    def test__some_function__called(self):
        some_class_module = importlib('some_package.SomeClass')  # this is the actual module
        some_class_module.some_function = Mock()
        ...
        SomeClass().some_method()
        some_class_module.some_function.assert_called()  # <- no more error - tests pass
```

This is how I solved this issue - if anyone has an alternative solution it would be great to hear it. Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.